# Apply recurring event on custom calendar list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar, recurring-events

I have created a simple custom calendar list using a sandboxed solution. I want to use recurring event, but that's not working with my created list, it's showing me an error message.

I am getting the error message as below

> Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.RecurrenceField.SetRecurrenceFields()
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.RecurrenceField.CompleteItemLoad()
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SaveButton.ActionBeforeSaveItem(SPContext itemContext)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SaveButton.SaveItem(SPContext itemContext, Boolean uploadMode, String checkInComment)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SaveButton.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e)
>    at System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args)
>    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>    at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
>    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
>    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
>    at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>    at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>   
>   code i have added in event recievere file is as like bellow spinet
>   [image]

and after this i am an adding feature id of site level feature in element.xml file of the list instance,after that i am rebuilding solution,publishing it and then uploading that published .wsp file in SharePoint using solution gallery and after that simple activating the site level feature that's it

Comment: can you share the error? Have you followed the error to the ULS logs?

Comment: okkk,am adding that to question for more clarification

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/73349/cannot-create-recurring-events-in-a-custom-calendar

Comment: yes i did??but the solution is marked as answered that i am not able to understand means that's not clear to me.

Comment: Feature Activated class will already be there in your event receiver. Please uncomment the class & add the code within that class & you are done.

Comment: no that class is not present there that's why I have added that class there

Comment: the screen capture of event reciever file i have an added that covers whole event receiver file except namespace declaration block

Comment: get the below code & insert it inside **public class Feature1EventReceiver : SPFeatureReceiver**

Comment: that also i did,and that shows me error as "Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain: An unexpected error has occurred"

Comment: but when i am creating a eventactivated class and adding this code within that class then there is no issue,it's getting execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below image for reference

[image]

Instead of creating the calendar through a feature element, You have to user c# code to create Calendar list from Event Receiver.

You can use below mentioned code in your `FeatureActivated` class in your feature event receiver.

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {


                SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID);
                SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Web.ID);
                SPList listExistCheck = web.Lists.TryGetList("Calendar List");
                SPList customList;
                if (listExistCheck == null)
                {
                    // Create calendar list and record returned guid
                    Guid customPagesListGuid = web.Lists.Add("Calendar List", "Calendar List", SPListTemplateType.Events);
                    //Get list from stored guid
                    customList = web.Lists[customPagesListGuid];
                    // Set list properties and add required content types

                    customList.Title = "Calendar List";
                    customList.OnQuickLaunch = true; // Set to true to display on the quick launch
                    customList.ContentTypesEnabled = true;
                    customList.Update();
                    customList.Update();
                    web.Update();
                }

        }
```

Comment: sorry hardik ,I am very new to share point  and that's why asking some stupid kind of questions.actually working with this event receiver here i have two features one for site level features and another one for site collection features,so where at which feature exactly i have to add the event receiver ??

Comment: Site level Feature

Comment: here at the SPSecurity. i am getting error,it says "the name SPSecurity does not exist in the current context"

Comment: you need to add the namespace called Microsoft.SharePoint

Comment: that's already  present there

Comment: I found some articles  and they are saying  like we can not use SPSecurity in sandbox solutions,is it true??because i am using sandbox solution here

Comment: Code was for SharePoint On-Premises. Please look into this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220043.aspx

Comment: Try removing SPSecurity Code blocks

Comment: Have you added Client DLL of SharePoint in your solution?

Comment: sorry,i don't have any idea regarding that one

Comment: but,if you are asking about .wsp file then I have added that to SharePoint through solution gallery

Comment: the approach you have mentioned that also not working it say's  ---Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain: An unexpected error has occurred.

Comment: Same code is working on my end. I had tried it in my Office 365 account.

Comment: that is sandbox solution or farm solution??

Comment: Sandbox Solution obviously

Comment: Don't Know what you are doing. but if possible, Please send me at least a screen capture of your solution. so i can help further.

Comment: the "calender list" you have mentioned in code,what is it??a solution name??

Comment: It will create a Events list with having the name  "Calendar List". You can change it as per your need.

Comment: Actually i am not able to post screen capture in comment box

Comment: Upload somewhere & post a link here..

Comment: i have added a code screen capture to question kindly review that one

Comment: Have you done it?

Comment: yes,but it still shows same error as Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain: An unexpected error has occurred

Comment: It is for SP2010 but method for feature receiver is same. Please check all the steps here... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg615458%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: The last thing you can do is. you can upload your code to google drive & i will do the changes & upload it back to some location

Comment: are you satisfied with my help? If my answers helping you than you can mark the answer and upvote it so others can get benefit of it. as i know this is the solution of your problem. As you are new to SharePoint so you might have some problem in following the steps from my answer. :):)

Comment: yes,off course,i need your email id to share file

Comment: If you are from india than please share me your contact details so i can help better

Comment: yes i am an Indian m from Pune maharashtra

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38329/discussion-on-answer-by-hardik-apply-recurring-event-on-custom-calendar-list).